# Could not initialize class com.genuitec.eclipse.code.webicons.WebIcon In Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, console

So I had a problem when I was just trying to print out something.  It said: Show Console View has encountered a problem. An internal error has occurred. Then I clicked on the "Details" button and it said "Could not initialize class com.genuitec.eclipse.code.webicons.WebIcon". If anyone could help, thanks a LOT!

Here's what I wrote:                  System.out.println("enter text here");

EDIT: I have a feeling it has something to do with my PC's Environment Variables.

Comment: That isn't a standard Eclipse class - are you using MyEclipse or something like that?

Comment: Uninstalling all plug-ins of Genuitec (Darkest Dark Theme, DevStyle, etc.) should fix this issue (_Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_). Be careful which plugins you install, as they can slow down your Eclipse and make it less secure.

Comment: @greg-449 I'm using standard Eclipse, with WindowBuilder Editor plugin installed.

Comment: Genuitec is not part of standard Eclipse

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, I know. I managed to fix it by uninstalling something called "CodeMix", which was made by Genuitec.  I have no clue how that got onto my PC.